# What is the best way for copy specific Data from an external VM

Tags: java, python, c++, batch-file, copy

I have to copy some specific data out from a external VM (eVM) from an other firm i don't work.

I have an other VM (aVM) that is analysing data.
So the path of the data should be eVM -> My_PC -> aVM. aVM have no access to eVM. But the whole process should be controlled on aVM.

The collection of the data should happened every day and it should be only for data with '_CPU2' in it. After that aVM will parse (with a parser i implemented in java) the data and send it to other programs.

What is the fastest and the most performant way to implement this process? I do not want to collect not necessary data from eVM and i do not want to leave garbage on this PCs.

My primary languages are Java and python. Also I know the basics from c/c++. I have no big experience. Maybe there are some good classes or functions for it, you can advise me.

Is there maybe a way to do it through batch-files? I want to do it fast, because I will not have much time tomorrow for implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a shell that has linux/UNIX commands (If I'm on Windows, I use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)), then you could set up a [`Cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job or write a bash script to run on each machine that takes data from a known directory and uses [`scp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) to copy any data from that known directory on eVM to My_PC, then have another `cron` job (or bash script) from your PC 'forward' the data to aVM.

Links:

[Cron Resource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

[SCP Resource](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye)